# Assembly jmp not jumping

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

The problem is that it does not jump at `doi` even if `dl` and `bl` are equal. Anyone knows why?

```
assume cs:code,ds:data
data segment
sir1 db "abc"
l1 equ $-sir1
sir2 db "a"
l2 equ $-sir2
bunbun db "Este!$"
nu db "NU este!$"
iesire db "Apasa Enter!$"

data ends

code segment
start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    mov bp,offset sir1
    mov si,offset sir2
    dec bp
    push bp
    push si
    mov ah,l1
    mov bh,l2

unu:
    pop si
    pop bp
    inc bp
    dec ah
    mov dl,sir1[bp]
    mov bl,sir2[si]
    push bp
    push si
    cmp dl,bl
    je doi
    cmp ah,0
    je nu_bun
    jmp unu

doi:
    inc si
    inc bp
    dec ah
    mov dl,sir1[bp]
    mov bl,sir2[si]
    cmp dl,bl
    jne unu
    cmp bh,0
    je bun
    jmp doi

bun:
    mov dx,offset bunbun
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx,offset iesire
    int 21h
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h

nu_bun:
    mov dx,offset nu
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx,offset iesire
    int 21h
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Comment: How are you determining that `dl` and `bl` are equal? `[bp]` defaults to `ss:[bp]`... which is not where your string is. Try `di` instead of `bp` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compares implicit-length 0-terminated strings.  (Unlike the strings in the question that are either explicit length (with `l1 equ $-sir1` but no special byte marking the end) or have a `$` terminator.)

It also assumes ES = DS, or that the 2nd string is pointed to by ES:BP.  (The question is using `[BP]` for one of them, which is probably a mistake unless you're using a "tiny" code model where DS = SS.)

```
doi:
   ; cld             ; assume DF=0
    xchg di, bp
    mov cx, ax
    xor ax, ax

cmp_next:            ; do{
    lodsb              ; AL = [si]        ; si++
    scasb              ; cmp al, [es:di]  ; di++
    jnz not_equal
    test  al, al
    jnz   cmp_next   ; }while(al!=0);
   ; else fall through if we reached the end without finding a difference
do_equal:
    xchg di, bp
    mov ax, cx
    jmp somewhere_togo_when_equal

not_equal:
    xchg di, bp
    mov ax, cx
    jmp somewhere_togo_when_not_equal
```

Comment: What's the point of `dec si` / `cmpsb`?  Why not use `scasb`?  Also, `or al,al` is worse than `test al,al` on most CPUs.  Also, use `jnz cmp_next` like a normal person, instead of `jz` over a `jmp`.  This is a pretty bad example, and doesn't explain what's actually wrong with the question.  (Which is too much of a mess...)

Comment: @PeterCordes I tend to let the code explain itself, so the form as is. I don't really know what OP would like to do when the bytes equal or unequal, so I made both branches 'seeable'. It might not be the good practice in coding, but I tried to reduce the knowledge of the instruction set and implied flags change.

Comment: You can put a label (or comment) on the fall-through path and still write a simple loop with a standard `test/jnz` at the bottom.  If you want it to be simpler to understand for people with limited knowledge of the ISA, use `cmp al, 0` / `jne`.  (And in this specific case, for `al`, it's still the same code-size as `test al,al`).  Using `or` to set flags, and using complicated instructions like `lodsb` and `cmpsb` is the opposite of keeping it simple, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes For the answer was accepted then, it seemed help OP address his/her problem in code. I'd consider to keep it as is, however, please feel free to revise :)